# How to disable SSL in WSO2 APIM 3.0.0?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm running WSO2APIM 3.0.0 in Openshift. I'm trying disable SSL in WSO2APIM which mean WSO2APIM will only run on HTTP ( no longer HTTPS). I added this configure to deployment.toml:

```
[transport.https.properties] 
enable = false
```

But it seems to not work.

I think that, in this new version of WSO2APIM 3.0.0, we just need to configure in deployment.toml.
So is there some guide to solve this ? And I need some reference which describe all properties I can configure in deployment.toml.

Thank you all.

Comment: Hope you want to start apim http (9763 instead of 9443)?

Comment: But it already star both HTTP and HTTPS. I need disable HTTPS because when I access through HTTP, it still redirect to HTTPS. Maybe because the default context is HTTPS port 9443

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following properties as system properties to wso2server.sh file which resides in wso2am-3.0.0/bin location.

```
-Dhttpclient.hostnameVerifier=AllowAll \
-Dorg.opensaml.httpclient.https.disableHostnameVerification=true \
```

Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Enabling+HostName+Verification

Comment: Im afraid that it will not solve, because I need to turn off HTTPS, I need WSO2APIM run on just HTTP.

Comment: this is just to disable hostname verification.